# pandas: create a new date time column by combining existing columns

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to create a new datetime column from existing columns (one datetime column and another integer column) in a pandas data frame. Here is my code:

```
import datetime
df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'])
df['end_date'] = df['start_date'] + pd.Timedelta(df.total_waiting_days, unit='D')
```

But I got the following errors:

```
ValueError: Value must be Timedelta, string, integer, float, timedelta or convertible
```

What did I do wrong here and how do I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: pd.to_datetime(df['start_date']) + pd.Timedelta(df.total_waiting_days, unit='D')..............

Comment: @Wen : still same error by doing above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want to convert whole column to Timedelta

```
df['end_date'] = df['start_date'] + df.total_waiting_days.apply(lambda x :pd.Timedelta(x, unit='D'))
```